# lubridate::today() the argument tzone has no effect

Tags: r, lubridate

In `today()` in the `lubridate` package the argument `tzone` has no effect. it always gives "UTC":

```
> tz(today("Europe/Rome"))
[1] "UTC"

tz(today("GMT"))
[1] "UTC"
tz(today("EST"))
[1] "UTC"
tz(today("Europe/Rome"))
[1] "UTC"
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: I believe `tzone` gives the date you want to convert *from*, i.e. "what date is it in time zone `tz` right now?"

Comment: Ah yes.  that is the case. could you answer and i approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `tzone` gives the date you want to convert *from*, i.e. "what date is it in time zone `tz` right now?"  For example, at this moment (12:30 PM eastern daylight time/2:30 AM in Canberra)

```
today("Australia/Canberra")
[1] "2017-06-27"
today()
[1] "2017-06-26"
today("UTC")
[1] "2017-06-26"
```

But the time zone attribute of all of these is UTC: use `tz() <-` to set the time zone